# javascript array within array toString()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array like this:

```
temp = [
'data1',
['data1_a','data1_b'],
['data2_a','data2_b','data2_c']
];
//
```

I want to change the array within my array using toString(), how the best to do it?
Then the array like :

```
temp = [
'data1',
'data1_a,data1_b',
'data2_a,data2_b,data2_c
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with `.join()`:

```js
let temp = [
  'data1',
  ['data1_a','data1_b'],
  ['data2_a','data2_b','data2_c']
];

let result = temp.map(v => Array.isArray(v) ? v.join(",") : v);

console.log(result);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Answer (score 6):

use `map` and get that desired output. No need for any other complex methods or functions,

```js
var temp = [
  'data1',
  ['data1_a','data1_b'],
  ['data2_a','data2_b','data2_c']
];


var res = temp.map((item) => item.toString());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just map it and return the stringified version. There's no need for any checks - the strings will just be unmodified, the arrays will be converted like you want them

```js
temp = [
  'data1', ['data1_a', 'data1_b'],
  ['data2_a', 'data2_b', 'data2_c']
];

let foo = temp.map(String);
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: but if i provide NULL in array, this NULL will be 'null', how to give this empty??

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
temp = [
'data1',
['data1_a','data1_b'],
['data2_a','data2_b','data2_c']
];

for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i ++) {
    temp[i] += "";
}

console.log(temp);
```